# Create transaction with bitcoin core

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

Currently i'm working with bitcoin-qt for a while and now i have some issue that i wanna ask.

-Is there a way to create transaction then submit it to network from wallet that NOT inside this bitcoin core. Currently i only know that we only can create transaction for only account/address in our node.
So can anyone have any idea ?

Comment: signrawtransaction accepts private keys as parameters.

Comment: yes, i also look about that method too, but since you have to get listunspent to get txid for creatrawtransaction, so how we do it in our current node? We cannot listunspent address that outside our node.

Comment: You can add addresses as watch only

Comment: How will you sign it that’s the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. Bitcoin Core has various utility RPCs which are separate from the wallet. You can use `createrawtransaction` to create a transaction. Of course, without the wallet, you will need to specify the inputs and outputs for the transaction manually. You can sign that transaction with a private key not in the wallet by using `signrawtransactionwithkey`. You can then broadcast that transaction using `sendrawtransaction`.

To get the outputs for an address that you can use in `createrawtransaction`, you can use `scantxoutset` to scan the UTXO set for UTXOs pertaining to a particular address.

All of these can be done without the internal wallet and separate from the internal wallet.