# Is there an API to create transactions in the Bitcoin blockchain with only a private key?

Tags: blockchain.info, raw-transaction

Is there an API to create transactions in the Bitcoin blockchain with only a private key?

I am new to working with the Bitcoin and using its API. So, I have searched the API documentation. And [here](https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_wallet_api) is what I have found.

It seems that I need the Bitcoin wallet to work with the Bitcoin blockchain API. Since the password to the wallet is required in almost every endpoint.

That is kind of confuses me very much. Since, I thought that the main purpose of the cryptocurrency is to avoid the third party management and presence in the transactions and the wallet is exactly the third party which right there.

So, I hope that someone here would be able to point me to a different documentation, which would allow me to conduct transactions by only having a private key. Or at least explain why there is such a huge discrepancy in the intentions and the current state of affairs: why does the Bitcoin blockchain has the third party in it?

Here is my objective: conduct transactions by only having a private key. The objective has led me to asking the question.

Comment: Bitcoin https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin doesn't have any 3rd parties. Blockchain.com is privately held company around cryptocurrencies, not even bitcoin focused. You can use some public libraries or even guis to create a transaction, and not having bitcoin node you can publish it here: https://blockstream.info/tx/push

Comment: @TonySanak, thank you very much. I will look in the resources you have linked. (y)

Comment: @TonySanak, are there any instructions on how could I conduct a transaction [here](https://blockstream.info/tx/push)?

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/80039/create-transaction-with-bitcoin-core or https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/how-to-redeem-a-basic-tx please read it for beginning :)

Comment: @TonySanak, thank you very much. I am still stuck. I can not understand where can I find a clear description of the REST endpoints for the bitcoin blockchain. I would expect something like an API endpoint which given a private key would allow me to get a balance and then an endpoint which given two public keys and amount would allow me to conduct a transaction. Does such API exist?